# How to refresh the return value from myHelper method?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I have following handlebar and helper method

Handlebar

```
{{myHelper grp.group_name optionBinding=data}}
```

where data looks like  => Object {Eastern Group: 1} and  grp.group_name = 'Eastern Group'
Helper

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('myHelper', function(value, options) {
  console.log(options);
  var map = options.hash.optionBinding;

  return map[value];
});
```

since I am using registerBoundHelper-- with every change in data (which is a key/value object) return from myHelper should also refresh ?

Following is as per guide published at http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper

> Bound hash options are also supported. Example:
>
> {{repeat text countBinding="numRepeats"}}
>
> In this example, count will be bound to the value of the numRepeats
>   property on the context. If that property changes, the helper will be
>   re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the binding the wrong way, i think. Following the API link you mentioned, your implementation would have to look like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('myHelper', function(value, options) {
  console.log(options);
  var map = options.hash.option; //don't use Binding at the end

  return map[value];
});
```

When you use the helper and specify the attribute 'optionBinding', you are telling ember to create a binding from the value to the property 'option'. Therefore you have to use just 'option' when you want to access that value.

Comment: Only option doesnt work ...following is the **options obj** Object {hash: Object, contexts: Array[1], data: Object}
contexts: Array[1]
data: Object
hash: Object
**optionBinding: Object
Eastern Group: 1**
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: I am trying something like this 
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('helper', function(value) {
return value.get('name').toUpperCase();
}, 'name'); => "where name is dynamic" how to solve this ?

Comment: Can you post a new question including a fiddle? Then we can work it out together